# How to eliminate or disable the GNOME3 top panel?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I am using GNOME3 with Ubuntu 12.10. I am interested in using the new Cairo Dock which seems to replace the GNOME top panel. The trouble here is that the top panel overlaps the new Cairo upper docks.

How do I disable the GNOME Shell top panel?

I tried adding `display:none` to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`, but this accomplishes nothing.

Comment: I'm using gnome session fall back - iIF gnome 3 is similar alt-right click should provide option to remove panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove panel using gconf-editor 
Run

```
 gconf-editor
```

And navigate to desktop>gnome>session>required_components>panel and remove gnome-panel

Close the gconf-editor window and Reboot.